# JQuery Mobile CSS doesn't apply after AngularJS $http.get

Tags: css, ajax, html, angularjs

I'm creating an app with jQuery Mobile, Bootstrap and AngularJS, everything works fine until I get my data with AngularJS doing a `$http.get` request, then jQuery Mobile CSS doesn't apply for the list.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<ul data-role="listview" ng-controller="ejemplo">
    <li data-theme="a" ng-repeat="item in items"><a href="#">{{item.nombre}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
function ejemplo($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('http://balonmano100.p.ht/app/competiciones.php')
       .success(function(data) {
           $scope.items=data;
       });
 }
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: have you tried JQM's .refresh() against your list?

Comment: please make a plunker for this example so we can help you better

Comment: @CrimsonChin I have already added this `$("[data-role=listview]").listview("refresh");` at the end of the success callback function, but it does nothing. @Dan Kanze plunker??

Comment: You might be refreshing before angular render the UI.  Try injecting the $timeout service to your controller and use a very short timeout: 
    $scope.items = data;
    $timeout(function() { $("[data-role=listview]").listview("refresh")}, 5);  

Timeout usually execute after UI render.

Comment: ok, fixed, awesome, thanks very much I've been desperate for all day